# TypeScript narrowing argument type in constructor

Tags: typescript, types, constructor, narrowing

I have an entry class called `BackgroundLayer`. It takes two arguments, (1) the type of the background and (2) the configuration of that background. When (1) is type of `Background.Grid`, then the configuration needs to be of type GridBackgroundConfig. When (1) is type of `Background.Checkered` the configuration needs to be type of CheckeredBackgroundConfig. What I want is, when typing `new BackgroundLayer(Background.Grid`, the configuration (argument 2) needs to be type of GridBackgroundConfig. The source code below is my try, but it allows passing Background.Grid as (1) and an object of type CheckeredBackgroundConfig as (2) which shouldnt be allowed. I tried using multiple constructor implementations (`constructor(type: Background.Grid, config: GridBackgroundConfig); constructor(type: BackgroundEnum.Checkered,config: CheckeredBackgroundConfig);` but then I need to create a new constructor for every entry in `Background` manually. I wondered if it was possible to narrow the type of the second argument, if the type of the first argument is known.

```
enum Background {
    Grid = "Grid";
    Checkered = "Checkered";
}

interface LayerConfig {
    /* ... */
}

interface GridBackgroundConfig extends LayerConfig {
    /* ... */
}

interface CheckeredBackgroundConfig extends LayerConfig {
    /* ... */
}

class Layer {
    protected config: LayerConfig;

    constructor(config: LayerConfig) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}

class BackgroundLayer extends Layer {
    private background: Background;

    constructor(type: Background, config: GridBackgroundConfig | CheckeredBackgroundConfig) {
        super(config);

        if (type === Background.Grid) {
            this.background = new Grid(config as GridbackgroundConfig);
        } else if (type === Background.Checkered) {
            this.background = new Checkered(config as CheckeredBackgroundConfig);
        } else {
            throw "check argument types";
        }
    }
}

class Grid {
    private config: GridBackgroundConfig;

    constructor(config: GridBackgroundConfig) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}

class Checkered {
    private config: CheckeredBackgroundConfig;

    constructor(config: CheckeredBackgroundConfig) {
        this.config = config;
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if we did, you would still have to manually add in cases - I'd just stick with overloads as they're more explicit and it'll be easier to read and maintain later.

Comment: the number of cases probably wont even be in the double digits so this would be a solution. however I do wonder if and how it could be achieved. when adding an event listener for example, once you typed your event type (e.g. "mousemove"), it automatically knows, that the type of the event argument of the handler is MouseEvent, and it shows this to the user (in vs code). How is something like this achieved? It can determine the type of the event argument from the handler function based on the event typed given as first argument.

Comment: See [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2zL9w).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! you can post it as an answer and Ill accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably stick with using overloads here, but anyways, if you define a type that maps background types to their respective configs...

```
type ConfigMap = {
    [Background.Grid]: GridBackgroundConfig;
    [Background.Checkered]: CheckeredBackgroundConfig;
};
```

You should be able to make your class generic and edit the constructor to use the type parameter:

```
class BackgroundLayer<Type extends Background> extends Layer {
    private background: Grid | Checkered;

    constructor(type: Type, config: ConfigMap[Type]) {
```

Then the type of `config` depends on what was given to `type`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w2zL9w)